# How can i test facebook Authentication to my web site on localhost

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, localhost

im working on localhost server for the development , i like to implement the fb Authentication
shown [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) but when i try the code in the examples ( with the login button ) 
i can't see the button .
i set the hosts in my pc to www.mysite.com 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What URL did you specify in you app's settings on facebook?  Is it set to the correct mysite.com url there?  What I do is I have 1 app for my dev environment, 1 for my test/qa environment, and 1 app for prod environment.  This way I don't have too worry about overlap or changing settings.  Set once and forget.  Maybe you could benefit from such a setup.

Comment: well still i need the dev to be in localhost.
i set in the "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" section 
this : 
http://myapp.com:9090/myapp/index.php

Comment: hmmm. maybe facebook is expecting to see myapp.com:9090 publicly.  Can you try setting it to localhost on port 80 and see if that helps?

Comment: I'd say something is messed up with that app.  Try starting with a new app id and reentering all the information for your dev environment.  Be sure to use http://localhost/myapp/index.php for the url in the new settings.